# CSS printing issue in Firefox and IE

Tags: css, printing-web-page

I'm trying to print [this page](http://www.calibredesign.com/clients/spec/index.html?view=t_fabr.html) under the link **graded fabric ArcCom** in IE and Firefox. However, it's only printing the first page, without the complete table. How can I fix this problem? Any suggestion?

Comment: Not programming-related. Belongs on Superuser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you mean link “graded fabrics,” which points to http://www.calibredesign.com/clients/spec/fps_fabric_arc.html (though if you follow the link the simple way, this page opens in a frame). Viewed separately (after right-clicking on the link and selecting “Open in new window”) it seems to get printed OK.

The reason why it does not print OK when opened in a frameset may depend on the large number of HTML syntax errors on the page. Errors like missing `</table>` tags may confuse browsers in printing.